# ADB Equivalent for ThreadX

Tags: adb, rtos, threadx, azure-rtos

I'm interested in looking into the ThreadX RTOS and was wondering if anyone knew if there was an adb type equivalent in ThreadX. I'm imagining using a device with ThreadX and using some adb-like tool to view hte file system or push files to the device.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreadX is intended for devices much smaller than anything that runs Android; you must give up on the idea that there will be any debug facility incorporated in your target.  With embedded devices, your debug capabilities are in the development tools which run on a Windows PC (and yes, most embedded tools only run on Windows) attached to the target.  That said, there are excellent debug tools built into any embedded IDEs these days.

If you are interested in ThreadX, get a development board from Renesas that incorporates a debugger link.  These are typically available for less than $50 USD.  The Renesas IDE, E2Studio, has great support for ThreadX.  I also understand that the watch from Pine64 runs ThreadX but I am awaiting that device's arrival and have not used the Nordic tools before so I can't say how well ThreadX is integrated into that.

Finally, and I have no vested interest in this, if you are starting in embedded code you might want to check out FreeRTOS instead of ThreadX.  I can't say it is superior in any technical way; but, if you search here you'll see there is a much bigger community of FreeRTOS users than ThreadX.  To me, they both work fine, its easier to find help with FreeRTOS as a quick search will reveal 10x the postings for FreeRTOS vs ThreadX.

Comment: Can I use the IDE and E2Studio to develop on other boards too? Or are they both specific to Renesas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure RTOS has a component called Azure RTOS TraceX which can be used understand threadx services(threads, queues) usage. This is a windows based tool. I don't have experience using the same but i think it is possible. I think your threadx needs to complied with the Tracex enabled, and it can create tracex event buffer which can then be used with the tool. If you are using Filex and some sort of memory i think theoretically it can be exported easily. Otherwise you can use print dumps or some similar hack to get it. I might try this soon and will update.

**NOTE: I haven't used TraceX yet so this is all in theory. But most probably possible**